# Find height of cone point in blueprint

Tags: metallurgy, technical-drawing, drawings

In this blueprint I was not able to find where the height of the point of the cone angle should be.
[image]

Here's the original blueprints:
http://library.centerofthewest.org/digital/collection/WRAC/id/398/rec/8743
http://library.centerofthewest.org/digital/collection/WRAC/id/2664/rec/8855
http://library.centerofthewest.org/digital/collection/WRAC/id/397/rec/8742

How can I find the height of this point in relation to origin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The height of the center can be found from the .208R+.003 dimension. The lowest point of this radius is dimensioned vs a nearby flat face with .025±.002.

The reason the center is not dimensioned directly from any flat face will be to do with the design intent and tolerance stackups. The dimension that *matters*, is the distance from the flat to the surface of the cone (.025±.002) - not the distance to the centre.

[image: marked up print]

Comment: You're right. I'll delete my answer despite the nice jaggy drop shadow detail. (https://greenshot.org).